# Numeric type signature

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems, type-level-computation

Is it possible to create a type with a numeric argument?

i.e. if I want to create a type of integers with a fixed bit-width:

```
newtype FixedWidth w = FixedWidth Integer

addFixedWidth :: FixedWidth w -> FixedWidth w -> FixedWidth (w+1)
mulFixedWidth :: FixedWidth w -> FixedWidth w -> FixedWidth (2*w)
```

So that the type-checker only allows `FixedWidth`s of the same type to be added or multiplied, but also determines the correct precision of the result.

I know you can do something like this:

```
data Nil = Nil
data Succ x = Succ

addFixedWidth :: FixedWidth w -> FixedWidth w -> FixedWidth (Succ w)
```

and represent the number 4 as `Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Nil))))`, but that's incredibly ugly.  I also need to figure out how to append two `Succ`s for the multiply result type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is **type-level naturals**, know as the `-XTypeNats` extension to Haskell.

At the moment this is possibly only in an *experimental branch* of GHC. It is likely to merge into GHC by 7.4 I think.

Some further reading:

- [TypeNats](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeNats), GHC wiki page.
- [Type-Level Naturals Basics](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeNats/Basics)
- [Ticket #4385](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4385).
- [The TypeNats branch of GHC](http://code.galois.com/darcs/type-naturals/)